# What is the meaning of “they are out of hit points”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, slang

I'd like to know the meaning of '*be out of hit points*.'

For example like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Why have you posted two similar questions? [Is this grammatical? 'Looks like a couple of Pikachus are out of hit points'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109874/is-this-grammatical-looks-like-a-couple-of-pikachus-are-out-of-hit-points) Is this newer question the one really wanted to  ask?

Comment: The question I asked before was solved. I just would like to know the meaning of 'be out of hit points.'

Answer (score 10):

The phrase **hit points** is a gaming term, from the realm of role-playing games.

Here's the definition pulled from [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+hit+point&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8):

> (gaming) Health is usually measured in **hit points** or **health points**, often shortened as HP. When the HP of a player character reaches zero, the player may lose a life or their character might become incapacitated or die

Someone is using a gaming term in this meme, saying that some of the Pikachus (in this case, the ones that are broken in half, I believe) don't look fully healthy. It's meant to be humorous.

Comment: (+1) The Pikachus in the image, either with full hit points or not-so-full hit points, will be turned into eat points by the owner.

Answer (score 5):

To be "out of" something means to have none of them (or none of it) remaining.  If a carpenter is **out of** nails, he has no nails remaining in his nail pouch.  If a supermarket is **out of** bread, the bread shelf is empty.  If a bakery is **out of** flour, its flour bins are empty.

The nails have been used up.  All of the bread has been purchased. All of the flour has been made into bread.

Comment: Interesting how we assumed the OP needed help in two different places. Between our two answers, we should have this covered.  :-)  This is also a good example why so many regulars clamor for OPs to share their research, and explain [clearly](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) which part of a phrase they do not understand.

Comment: Yes, I'd say we have it covered. And it's a good thing, because the pictures suggest the phrase has something to do with Pikachu population growth.